# How to install my .xpi on firefox-beta android

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a private xpi file signed by the Add-on Development Center. I would like to install this on android's firefox-beta (firefox-beta 79.1.0-beta-1). However, when you install it, the download is completed, and when you "Open"

> The file could not be opened.

Is displayed and installation is not possible. If you do the same operation with firefox 68.11.0 on android, xpi will be installed successfully.

Originally, I wanted to do remote debugging, and I needed firefox-beta or nightly for remote debugging, so I'm trying to install xpi on beta.

Also, there seems to be a way to make html, download xpi with a link from there, and install it, but with this method,

> firefox beta cannot download this file type

It will be displayed. (it is japanese message.)

Please tell me.